# Passing data from a Google Form to an new Form when 'Submit another response' is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am attempting to design a form to collect data for a competition entries. Any entrant can make a number of entries all under the same *name* (identification), but with different *details* for each entry. The competition is open to the public, hence no prior knowledge of the names of entrants.

When the form is submitted the option for 'Submit another response appears'. 
1. How do I pass the *name* information to the second form? 
2. And preferably give the option of doing so or not?

I have checked out answers to [Is it possible to 'prefill' a google form using data from a google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108511/is-it-possible-to-prefill-a-google-form-using-data-from-a-google-spreadsheet) and [Prefill a Google Form using data from the last response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147287/prefill-a-google-form-using-data-from-the-last-response).

They both seem to suggest that I could read the *name* form the receiving spreadsheet after submitting, and prefill a new Form that way - however I am not clear on how I could do that prefill before the new Form is displayed.

At present a simple html form is used - *name* data has to be reinput each time - and the replies transferred to an Excel spreadsheet for processing. I think a Google based solution would be much easier for entrants and for user.

I am really just feeling my way with script for Forms so any help, especially on methods of approaching the problem, would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are not going to be able to have the user click the "Submit another response" link and have the next instance of the Form contain the name from the previous response.  Your only hope is to have the Form run an On Form Submit trigger, build/get a pre-filled URL, and then email the pre-filled URL to the person who first filled out the Form.  Another option would be to custom build a Web App with an input form.  Your question is "off topic" to Stack Overflow, because it is asking for general advice.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Sandy. You have confirmed what I was thinking; which led to the "off topic" question - it is very hard to be specific about something that is not do-able - though had there been a clear cut answer perhaps it would have been less "off topic".